# Remove animation between UITableView sections

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I have a UITableView with expanding sections (tap on the header and the rows appear below).

The app has an option to enter 'edit mode.' When you enter edit mode, all sections expand.

When you exit edit mode, all of the sections that were previously closed, close again automatically (technically all the cells for that section are deleted).

There appears to be a default animation in a UITableView that animates sections closing if all the cells are removed. I've been looking around and cannot seem to find any way to disable that from happening.

This is the code for removing a section and 'collapsing' the section:

```
-(void) removeSection:(int)sectionNum {

    NSArray *rowsToDelete = [self indexPathsInSection:sectionNum];

    [self deleteTableData:sectionNum];

    [self.myTable beginUpdates];

    [self.myTable deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:rowsToDelete withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];        
    [self.myTable endUpdates];   

}


-(void)deleteTableData:(int)sectionNum{

    [self.tableArray removeObjectAtIndex:sectionNum];
    NSArray *empty = [[NSArray alloc]init];
    [self.tableArray insertObject:empty atIndex:sectionNum]; 
    [empty release];

}
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: How do you get the "expanding sections" behavior? Can you show some relevant code?